# Set solr field values based on other fields

Tags: solr, solr8

I have three fields in the Solr core:

- `Field1`,
- `Field2`,
- `Field3`.

I am setting a value for `Field1` and `Field2` in the DIH, but I want to set the value for `Field3` based on some values in Field1 and Field2.

For Example, `Field1` and `Field2` are the boolean types so I want to check if either Field1 or Field2 is **true** and then set the `Field3` value as **true** otherwise set **false**.

Comment: If you're using DIH you're probably fetching information from SQL - in that case, use an SQL statement (`IF ...`) to get a column with the value you want from your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve it is to use a script in your **DIH**, here is an example:

```
<document>
  <entity ...>
    <field column="..." name="Field1" />
    <field column="..." name="Field2" />
    
    <field name="Field3" script="Field1 || Field2" />
  </entity>
</document>
```